# Is it appropriate to have a "technologies used" section for each employer?

Tags: resume

I've had jobs both in the software development and IT fields, both using very different technologies with some overlap. I want to highlight that I am proficient in both areas. My original resume had a "Skills" section, however I feel like it would cause a bit of confusion due to the different technology stacks that I've used. I'm also torn because 2 jobs prior to my tech-specific jobs were both generic call center jobs, and therefore I wouldn't apply a "technologies used" section to those.

Would it be appropriate to have a "technologies used" under the appropriate employers? Or would it be better to do this some other way on my resume? Would it also be an issue to highlight proficiency with technologies on some of my past employers without listing the same thing on others?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Would it be appropriate to have a "technologies used" under the
>   appropriate employers?

While there's nothing inappropriate about what you are considering, it may just serve to confuse the reader. I've seen this a number of times, particularly with contracts, and found it a poor way to communicate what the applicant knew.

Employers are unlikely to care *where* you used particular technologies. Spreading your technology skills across a number of employers could make those skills harder to grasp in the aggregate, and will likely diminish their impact.

Instead, put these technologies in your Skills section, where most resume readers will expect to find them.

When an interviewer asks "Where did you use technology X?" then you can expand on where and when your skills were applied.

Comment: Alright, great to hear. This is what I was doing before, but I wanted to try it this way mainly to see if it would work better. I agree that it might be confusing, thanks again!